# Handling Different Sets of Data

Tags: c#, oop, architecture

Im having design/ architecture issues in how I am putting together my code. For example right now I store data in:

```
internal interface IProperty<TKey1, TKey2> : IDictionary<TKey1, TKey2> { }

internal class PropertyDictionary<TKey1, TKey2> : IProperty<TKey1, TKey2>
```

I implement IDictionary in PropertyDictionary. Also with PropertyDictionary i can then have a key and then for the value an immutable object with public properties. I can then reference the data easily by:

```
        foreach (var data in inputData.Values)
        {
              var propertyValue = data.MyDataProperty;
        }
```

Firstly this way seems a lot of overhead to store data but more importantly now when I need to extend the functionality of PropertyDictionary for example to include RetrievePrice it becomes complicated as I need to add the additional methods in an interface and then create a new class as so:

```
internal interface IAssetPriceData<in TKey1>
{
    double RetrievePrice(TKey1 key);
}

internal class PriceDictionary<TKey1, TKey2> : PropertyDictionary<TKey1, TKey2>, IAssetPriceData<TKey1>
```

So a solution on how I should structure my code to easily store different types of data which is then easily retrieved so I can manipulate / perform calculation on the properties that are being stored.

Comment: Why not use the default data structures provided in .net and add the functionality you need with extension methods?

Comment: if i implement IDictionary i can change small things like check if the key exists. But even if I do implement the Dictionary I would still have the issue of extending its functionality at times.

Comment: Dictionary already has support for checking if a key exists, and you can add your own extension methods to it without having to use a derived type.

Comment: after further investigation what I was looking for was Property Bags which give me the ability to better store and access data!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I wrote a class somewhat like the one described here once (below).  I was grouping properties of the same type for some WPF binding scenarios, and binding to dictionary elements.  I didn't want to use a dictionary because of the key not found exception that would be raise (and eaten) by the framework.  This one wraps a dictionary and hardcodes strings as keys, though it could probably be generalized to suit the purpose described here.  The main item of note is the behavior of the indexer when key is not found -- it returns the default T instead of throwing exception.

/// This class represents a generic collection of things for binding
    /// Hash items is never null, Indexer never throws exceptions, returning defaults on cache miss
    public class BindableHash : IEnumerable
    {
        #region Fields

```
    /// <summary>Current implementation of the hash is a dictionary</summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<string, T> _HashItems = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>How many items are currently in the hash</summary>
    public virtual int Count { get { return _HashItems.Count; } }

    /// <summary>Indexer provides hashed (by string) lookup</summary>
    public virtual T this[string index]
    {
        get { return index != null && _HashItems.ContainsKey(index) ? _HashItems[index] : default(T); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>Default constructor initializes hash with no members</summary>
    public BindableHash() : this(null) { }

    /// <summary>Injected constructor seeds the list using the tuples passsed in</summary>
    public BindableHash(params Tuple<string, T>[] initialTuples)
    {
        foreach (Tuple<string, T> tuple in initialTuples ?? new Tuple<string, T>[] { })
        {
            Add(tuple);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>Add a key-value pair to the hash</summary>
    public virtual void Add(string key, T value)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<string, T>(key, value));
    }

    /// <summary>Removes all items from the hash</summary>
    public virtual void Clear()
    {
        _HashItems.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>Remove a particular value from the hash</summary>
    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        return key != null && _HashItems.Remove(key);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    /// <summary>Abstraction for adding a key value pair</summary>
    protected void Add(Tuple<string, T> tuple)
    {
        if (tuple != null && tuple.Item1 != null)
        {
            _HashItems[tuple.Item1] = tuple.Item2;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    /// <summary>Define enumerator retrieval to allow enumeration over values</summary>
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T value in _HashItems.Values)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    /// <summary>Impelementation for clients who cast this as non-generic IEnumerable</summary>
    /// <remarks>If you're not familiar with the black magic going on here, IEnmerable generic interface inherits from
    /// IEnumerable non-generic (legacy).  Both interfaces define GetEnumerator, and one returns a generic IEnumerator and the other
    /// a non-generic IEnumerator.  This one is the non-generic, and we want to 'hide' it for type safety purposes.  When you 
    /// do an explicit interface implementation, you create some kind of visibility purgatory.  This method is not private/protected
    /// because the interface is public, but it is also not a public method of this class.  The only way you can get to this guy is by casting
    /// BindableHash as IEnumerable (non-generic) and invoking the method that way.  Since that is possible to do, we have to implement the method,
    /// which we do by just invoking our generic one.  This is legal because of the fact that IEnumerator generic inherits from non-generic IEnumerator.
    /// Clear as mud?  You can ask me for a more detailed explanation, if you like --ebd</remarks>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```